# Salting passwords?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working register and login script, but I want to salt the passwords to make sure they are secure against hackers and sql injections

How do I do this?
This is my code as follows;
thanks
HTML

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newUsername" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="submit" name="signUp" value="Sign Up!"/>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="LogIn" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

Then PHP:

```
if($_POST['signUp']) {
    $username = $_POST['newUsername'];
    $pass = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $signedUp = SignUp($Username,$pass);
    echo $signUpCode[$signedUp]; // See the SignUp function in prefunc.php

} elseif($_POST['LogIn']) {
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $loggedIn = LogIn($username,$password);
    echo $logInCode[$loggedIn];

}

$signUpCode = Array(
    "-3"=>"Logged in already - can't sign up!",
    "-2"=>"Username already exists!",
    "-1"=>"Failed to sign up - please try again!",
    "1"=>"Signed up, and logged in successfully!"
);

function SignUp($Username,$Password) { 
    $Username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","",$Username);
    $u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Username)=LOWER('$Username')");

    if(getCurrentId()){
        return -3;
    }

    if(!mysql_num_rows($u)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET Username='$Username',Password=''$Password") or die(mysql_error());
        $u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Username)=LOWER('$Username')");

    if(mysql_num_rows($u)) {
        LogIn($Username,$Password);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

return -2;
```

}

Comment: Just a heads up, as your interest is in fact security you should no longer use the native mysql functions as they have been deprecated. Have a look on mysqli and PDO instead.

Comment: Can you please post how your Users table is defined? mysql: desc Users;

Comment: You say your script works, but it shouldn't. You have `$password` outside of the quotes. Salting isn't going to protect you against SQL injection vulnerabilities (which you have by the way - a password with a quote character in it will break your query.) - Don't use `mysql_*` functions, and look into mysqli/PDO prepared statements.

Comment: You can't get help here w/o showing us the "LogIn" function. And by the way, there's no need to do LOWER()=LOWER(). In MySQL string comparisons are always case-insensitive.

Comment: As has already been said: 1) do *NOT* use mysql_xxx()". Use [mysqli](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) or PDO instead.  2) *DO* use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_stmt_init.asp). 3) Do *NOT* store the password in clear-text.  Encrypt ... or better, use a one-way hash. 4) Also: look here: http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @OlegDubas Incorrect about string comparisons in MySQL ALWAYS being case insensitive.  Case sensitivity depends on the collation being used for the column in question. There are case sensitive collations.

Comment: @MikeBrant thanks for the correction. Good to remember that!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

- You need to consider using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for this purpose.  These are the best "out of the box" functions in PHP for password hashing

Usage example:

```
$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password_hash}')";
```

- There should be no reason whatsoever to first check the existence of a user before trying to insert one. As long as you have a unique index on your Username field, the insert will just fail if it is duplicate Username. This saves you an extra query against your DB every time you try to create a user.  You also should not be messaging a user that a username already exists, as this is bad security practice.  The user insert query should just succeed or fail, for cases where failure is due to duplicate key on insert, you should not care.
- You should not be using `mysql_*` functionality for anything. This is deprecated functionality.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.
- Along with using `mysqli` or `PDO` you should be using prepared statements with bound parameters. Currently your code is subject to SQL injection as you are doing nothing to escape the user input before trying to use it in your query.  Very, very bad practice.

Using a parametrized prepared statement, your query would look something like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES (:username, :password_hash)";
```

You would then prepare and execute this.  I am not going to go into detail here as there are hundred of thousands of examples on the web of how to do this.

Comment: you should *always* care why it fails, or you can't debug your code.

Comment: @Octopus I meant specifically you should not care if the insert itself fails.  You certainly do need to care whether you are getting syntax errors or something else that would suggest a code problem. A failed insert on duplicate key should not be considered a problem in this case. I will update my answer to make this clearer.